# How to organize and show in a ListView my Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>>

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, listview, dart

I have one main map: `Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _myEvents;`. Within this variable I store many events related to days one ex: `{2020-12-23 12:00:00.000Z: [{time: TimeOfDay(10:47), eventName: Navidad}]}`. My events are stored by day but now I want to show the list of events from a given month (each time user change the month I update the list with the month's events).

What I'm trying:

```dart
_setMonthEvents(first,last){
    _monthEvents.clear();
    for(int i = first.day; i <= last.day; i++){
      DateTime dayT = DateTime(first.year, first.month, i, first.hour,first.minute,first.second);

      if(_myEvents[dayT] != null){
        _monthEvents.addAll({'date': dayT, 'time': _myEvents[dayT][0]['time'], 'name': _myEvents[dayT][0]['name']});
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

But with this approach only the last events saved keeps in the _monthEvents : `{date: 2020-12-24 12:00:00.000Z, eventTime: TimeOfDay(12:30), eventName: Navidad}` and if I put another it subscribes it..

This is my ListView (to show the events)

```dart
ListView.builder(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: _monthEvents.length != null ? _monthEvents.length : 0,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            //
          },
          child: Dismissible(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), child: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded)),
                title: Text(_monthEvents.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), //returns the last insertion (the last event included)
                subtitle: Text(
                  _monthEvents.length.toString(), //returns 3 *always*
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)
                ),
              ),
              
          ),);
      },
    );
```

I think I've been doing it wrong. What is the best approach to achieve my expected result?

My current result: A list with three equal elements (the last I added) and with length 3.
My expected result: A list with all the events from all days (a day can have more than one event) from a given month

Comment: Instead of having a separate `_monthEvents` variable, I'd store everything in a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html), and then you could easily and directly iterate over all elements that are between two dates.

Comment: What if first `first` format is `2020-11-29` and `last` `2020-12-03` your function wont even run because `29 <= 03` will return false

Comment: I have another function treating it @dm_tr

Comment: @jamesdlin Could you show a brief of your approach?

Comment: @jamesdlin at first glance, a SplayTreeMap can indeed give you the next key before this one, and the next key after this one, but it implies that it has to be an existing key, and doesn't seem to offer ranges of lookup.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz There isn't an existing method, but you could easily implement a function to return a range by repeatedly calling [`firstKeyAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/firstKeyAfter.html).  Also, the key passed as the argument to `firstKeyAfter` (or to [`lastKeyBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/lastKeyBefore.html)) doesn't need to exist.

Comment: That'd be the same as just simply running the Iterator over the set, with no gain in that it was already sorted.  If you're gonna do that, I'd run a set.keys.where(...).

Comment: @RandalSchwzartz There isn't necessarily no gain.  Each call to `firstKeyAfter` or to `lastKeyBefore` should be O(log n) for a `SplayTreeMap`.  Retrieving a range of k elements therefore would be O(k log n), whereas `set.keys.where(...)` would be O(n).  Since usually k << n, the `SplayTreeMap` should give better asymptotic performance for large maps.  Granted, I'm ignoring the O(n log n) cost to build the `SplayTreeMap`, but if range-based lookups are performed much more often than insertions and single lookups, the `SplayTreeMap` should be better.